# Handling improvement request but not showing on the change page

Tags: bug, documentation

I handled an improvement request, then, after a comment from another user, I edited my Example before it was approved/rejected. And now it is approved but it is disassociated from the improvement request.

Here is the Change: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/74619?draftId=62092

And this is the improvement request: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/1757

Is this expected behaviour?