# "Handle improvement request" lost when draft edited

Tags: bug, documentation

I edited the [expression trees](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/75/expression-trees#t=201608110631156743154) example yesterday.  When I first edited, I clicked "Handle improvement request" and then clicked submit.  Later, I finished the draft and clicked submit again.  On the second submit, the draft was no longer marked to handle the request.  Also, now that the revision has been accepted, it is still marked as needs improvement.

Comment: This is the same issue I reported a few days ago: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330516/handling-improvement-request-but-not-showing-on-the-change-page?rq=1